# How do I make my gaming laptop use my descrete graphics card only?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I have an ASUS TUF Gaming A15 with an AMD Ryzen 7 4800H and a RTX 3050. I want my system to only use my discrete graphics card rather then having to right click the application and tell it to use my discrete graphics card from there. I have set it to performance mode but apparently it still by default shows to use the iGPU only? Is there a way to get around this?[image]